# this one is really some weird error which I haven't seen before and I can't deal with

Tags: javascript

```js
// Declare Variables;
var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
var theDay = document.getElementById("theDay")
  // Make the function , takes user's input , put it in the new Date Object >> Show the user the day...

function checkDate() {
  var date = new date(year, month, day)
  theDay.innerHTML = "You were born on " + date.slice(0, 3);
  return theDay
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  width: 1400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
}
input.input {
  width: 700px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
input.year {
  width: 700px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
button {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Your friend was born on Tuesday?<br /> You can also know!! Just complete the form</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the year .." id="year" class="input">
<br />
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the month.." id="month" class="input">
<br />
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the day.." id="day" class="input">
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="checkDate()">See The Day!!!</button>
<div id="theDay"></div>
```

When I try to run it , the console shows up an error >> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at line 13 >> (var year) 
I tried to put default values , didn't work , when I removed the . notation + value in each variable of year,month and day , it showed up another error , I just like this syntax and I don't want to change it to another way , if anybody has got a solution or can tell me where the wrong part is i'd be so thankful

Comment: Downvotes incoming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider revising your question to make sure that you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people are able to help you. Try to explain the *problem at hand*, *your result*, and the *expected result*.

Comment: Line 13 >> Input.year should be input#year , I already figured it out and solved it ...

Comment: It's the second time I put a question on here , I just posted the code and asked for help , that's it ...

Comment: Yo guys , I don't know how to post the "Perfect" question , I just wanted help .. I don't know how to use this website perfectly , excuse me if my question was that bad , but I just want a hand ..

Comment: The problem is the order. Your script get's executed before the body is (fully) loaded, therefore the Elements you try to access in this script don't exist yet, therefore you're trying to read the value of an input that doesn't exist yet, that is `null` at the moment. That's what the error is telling you. *solution: Put the script at the end of the body*.

Answer (score 1):

your javascript is running before the input elements have been "seen" by the browser - either

- move your code to the end of `<body>` (just above `</body>`); or
- change your code to run after DOM is "ready"; or
- move the variable assignment ( `year = document.getElementById("year").value;` etc) inside the checkDate function - you can declare the vars inside the function or outside, it doesn't really matter (preferably inside though)

The last option is probably the preferred -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Make the function , takes user's input , put it in the new Date Object >> Show the user the day...
        function checkDate(){
        // Declare Variables;
            var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
            var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
            var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
            var theDay = document.getElementById("theDay")
            var date = new date(year,month,day)
            theDay.innerHTML = "You were born on "+ date.slice(0,3);
            return theDay
        }
</script>
```

Comment: var theDay = document.getElementById("theDay"); can be kept out. Its just a reference to the DOM.

Comment: actually, without moving the code at all, you can't have `theDay` outside the function as then the ordering becomes an issue again

Comment: Okay Thanks , That worked but there was another issue , the answer was the same every time even if i change the numbers >> Thu Nov 30 1899.
Idk why ..

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `date.getDay()` function.
- Month index starts from zero.
- DOM value extractions aren`t one-time, hence need to be moved inside the callback.

```js
var theDay = document.getElementById("theDay")
  // Make the function , takes user's input , put it in the new Date Object >> Show the user the day...

var getName = (function() {
  var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return function(index) {
    return names[index];
  }
})();

function checkDate() {
  // Declare Variables;
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  // months are indexed from 0 in JS.
  var month = document.getElementById("month").value - 1;
  var day = document.getElementById("day").value;

  var date = new Date(year, month, day);
  theDay.innerHTML = "You were born on " + getName(date.getDay());
  return theDay
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
}
input.input {
  width: 700px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
input.year {
  width: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
button {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Your friend was born on Tuesday?<br /> You can also know!! Just complete the form</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the year .." id="year" class="input">
<br />
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the month.." id="month" class="input">
<br />
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the day.." id="day" class="input">
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="checkDate()">See The Day!!!</button>
<div id="theDay"></div>
```

Comment: Hey @Ahmed hope this helps. Please check the snippet above. There was some ordering issues.

Comment: Okay Thanks , That worked but there was another issue , the answer was the same every time even if i change the numbers >>Thu Nov 30 1899 .
Idk why ..